# Raspbian Buster Lite: couldn't communicate with wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

Just flashed a card with **Raspbian Buster Lite** on a Raspberry Pi 2, and ssh'd into it using an ethernet cable. `raspi-config`/`wpa_cli` can't communicate with `wpa_supplicant` (there's no `/var/run/wpa_supplicant` control interface).

At the end of the post I explain a workaround, but it's not permanent.

Here's some debugging information,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.97-v7+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:15:58 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps aux | grep wpa
root       289  0.0  0.4  10740  3976 ?        Ss   may02   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
pi         915  0.0  0.0   7356   496 pts/0    S+   00:00   0:00 grep --color=auto wpa
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service 
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-05-04 02:04:51 -03; 2min 50s ago
 Main PID: 602 (wpa_supplicant)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2200)
   Memory: 496.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
           └─602 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

may 04 02:04:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
may 04 02:04:51 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
may 04 02:04:51 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[602]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="****"
    psk="****"
}
```

As you can see, I've only edited the config with network's ssid/psk after failing at `raspi-config`.

Here's my usb wifi adapter / driver,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x8179 RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11n NIC
  iSerial                 3 00E04C0001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0027
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0002
  (Bus Powered)
  Remote Wakeup Enabled
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip addr show wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:a6:f7:1d:36:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /var/log/syslog
...
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.225728] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.324223] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.362213] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.939312] random: crng init done
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.939336] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.394678] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started triggerhappy global hotkey daemon.
May  3 00:04:04 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[288]: Successfully called chroot().
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[288]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[288]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[288]: Network interface enumeration completed.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[288]: Server startup complete. Host name is raspberrypi.local. Local service cookie is 2935413426.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[307]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi raspi-config[313]: Checking if shift key is held down:Error opening '/dev/input/event*': No such file or directory
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi raspi-config[313]:  No. Switching to ondemand scaling governor.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed).
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.661234] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dphys-swapfile - set up, mount/unmount, and delete a swap file.
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[306]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.679881] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[306]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[306]: eth0: carrier acquired
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi kernel: [   12.338131] MAC Address = 18:a6:f7:1d:36:90
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi kernel: [   12.341657] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
...
```

After reading some posts, people seems to have issues with the driver, so tried with `wext`,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pkill wpa_supplicant
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps aux | grep wpa
root       496  0.2  0.2  10996  2760 ?        Ss   01:58   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
```

That worked, and `wlan0` went up, but I'm not sure how to keep it permanent for reboot, because it's not clear who is responsable for starting wpa_supplicant, `dhcpcd` hooks (`10-wpa_supplicant.conf`)? `systemd`'s wpa_supplicant dbus service?

According to `ps aux` output, it's using the DBus service, and tried adding `-Dwext` parameter on `ExecStart` and rebooted but didn't work. It's like the default DBus version doesn't work. Is it expecting NetworkManager to be installed or something?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps aux | grep wpa
root       321  0.2  0.4  10740  3972 ?        Ss   01:56   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant -Dwext
```

When running wpa_supplicant using the default nl80211 I get this output,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

Comment: I am not sure that what you have listed is significant and fiddling with wpa_supplicant is unnecessary, but one thing is clear - you do not appear to have setup the Pi fully. Depending on what your network supports and the whether the WiFi chip supports it  but you have **NOT set country code** See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: For example, you can set up country code using `raspi-config`, right? I can't even do that because it fails communicating with wpa_supplicant control interface (there's no /var/run/wpa_supplicant created at boot). I had already set country code and rebooted and it doesn't matter, at least for my interface. `dhcpcd` doesn't seem to start wlan0, whereas starting wpa_supplicant setting `wext` driver manually does work.

Comment: I  can't say why  raspi-config is not changing the file - I don't use it but put a file called wpa_supplicant.conf  in the boot directory and reboot. `ls /sys/class/net` will show if there is a wireless interface - if not fiddling with other files is futile.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue: Raspberry Pi OS Buster Lite 2021-03-04 on a Raspberry Pi 3. I used a fully-complete `wpa_supplicant.conf` file and made no other changes.

Comment: Not just Lite either; Desktop too.

Comment: In my case, NetworkManager was trying to manage the wifi connection, and wpa_supplicant was not able to do its thing freely. I anyway wanted to use nmcli, once I switched, it worked.

Answer (score 7):

The approach described [here](https://rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/hardware/raspberrypi_wpa_supplicant_problem) worked for me. I had the same symptoms, albeit with a different RTL chip (RTL8192S / Edimax EW-7622UMn):

> the `wlan0` interface does not sense the carrier and `dhcpcd` refuses to configure it. It seems that `dhcpcd` does not acknowledge that it is a WiFi adapter, so we have to force it. Just add an interface section into `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
env ifwireless=1
env wpa_supplicant_driver=nl80211,wext
```

Then reload with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

This was on a Raspberry Pi Model B+ v1.2 running bullseye.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

$ uname -an
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63+ #1459 Wed Oct 6 16:40:27 BST 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7622 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd RTL8192S WLAN Adapter
...
```

It has survived at least one reboot so far!

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 4):

There are some settings that you always need for a proper configuration. First set option

```
country=??
```

outside a `network={..}` block in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and ?? with your country code. If you cannot use `raspi-config` for doing that, then edit wpa_supplicant.conf.

Then enable WiFi with

```
rpi ~$ rfkill unblock 0
```

It is not a good idea to use old background driver **wext**, even if it seems to work. You may encounter other problems with connections. In `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf` you can find a hint, that background driver **nl80211** is the default Linux interface:

> Note: ap_scan=2 should not be used with the nl80211 driver interface (the
>   current Linux interface). ap_scan=1 is optimized work working with nl80211.
>   For finding networks using hidden SSID, scan_ssid=1 in the network block can
>   be used with nl80211.

After setting this and your WiFi still doesn't work then you should not touch these settings. Instead look at other issues because these settings are always needed.

**Update:**
After some more digging I was able to reproduce your situation. It seems you do not have **dhcpcd** running. By default **wpa_supplicant** is running two times. One time from its package configuration on installation and one time called by **dhcpcd**. You can check this with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-05-05 22:46:15 BST; 18min ago
 Main PID: 511 (wpa_supplicant)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
           └─511 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

May 05 22:46:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 05 22:46:15 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[511]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 05 22:46:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
```

This is what you see from the package installation but that does not provide interfaces for management (only option `-O` for dbus interface). This service is not needed for special Raspbian **dhcpcd** networking and can be disabled. It only confuses people.

What you do not see is the second wpa_supplicant daemon started by **dhcpcd**.

```
rpi ~$ ps aux | grep wpa
root       511  0.0  0.1  10740  4028 ?        Ss   22:46   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       986  0.0  0.0  10984  1972 ?        Ss   23:14   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
pi        1029  0.0  0.0   7348   584 ttyS0    S+   23:15   0:00 grep --color=auto wpa
```

Have a look at the `CGroup`:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status dhcpcd.service
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-05-05 23:14:14 BST; 3min 48s ago
  Process: 970 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1006 (dhcpcd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─ 986 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
           └─1006 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w

May 05 23:14:13 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: eth0: IAID 32:7f:38:91
May 05 23:14:13 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.50.6
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: eth0: leased 192.168.50.6 for 3600 seconds
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.50.0/24
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.50.1
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[970]: forked to background, child pid 1006
May 05 23:14:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
May 05 23:14:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[1006]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

So you have to check why your **dhcpcd** is not running. Maybe you have just to enable and start it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now dhcpcd.service
```

Comment: already tried adding country. I've edited my post with output when using nl80211. `wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface`

Comment: @soundblaster I have updated the answer.

Comment: dhcpcd is running, in fact dhcpcd logs show: `control command: dhcpcd --denyinterfaces wlan0`. dhcpcd starts, but can't start wlan0, it's not in its CGroups. There's an issue either with the r8188eu driver and my TP-Link wireless adapter, or the ctrl_interface not being found. Neither wpa_cli or raspi-config can't access the ctrl_interface.

Comment: did a fresh install without modifying any file, I just want to configure WIFI using `raspi-config`

Comment: @soundblaster Seems you are mixing up things, very confusing. **wlan0** is an interface and has nothing to do with CGroups. `/sbin/wpa_supplicant` must be shown under CGroups from the output of `systemctl status dhcpcd.service`. That means that wpa_supplicant is started with a hook script of **dhcpcd**. Have you checked this?

Comment: when I said "it's not in its CGroups", I meant that `/sbin/wpa_supplicant` is not in `dhcp.service` CGroups. `dhcpcd` starts but doesn't start wpa_supplicant. When trying to start wpa_supplicant manually, I get `nl80211: driver does not support authentication/association or connect command`. Whereas using `-Dwext` it starts

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem, and I diagnosed it.

In short, the problem is your choice of WiFi adapter. The RTL8188EUS / r8188eu does not work properly with out of the box software configurations. This is evident in your log messages:

```
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[306]: eth0: waiting for carrier
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.679881] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[306]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
May  3 00:04:05 raspberrypi dhcpcd[306]: eth0: carrier acquired
```

Dhcpcd is *waiting for carrier* on both eth0 and wlan0, and does not find a carrier on wlan0, so it does not continue to configure the interface. Under normal circumstances, dhcpcd will see carrier immediately on the wlan0 interface, and start another instance of `wpa_supplicant` with interface-specific arguments, which can then be configured through `raspi-config` and `wpa_cli`.

At boot time, `systemd` starts `/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant`. I think this listens on DBUS for commands, but I don't know how to drive it from the command line.

If you plug in an RTL8188, this is what is logged:

```
Sep  5 16:47:55 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.758606] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.889394] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8179, bcdDevice= 0.00
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.889421] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.889439] usb 1-1.2: Product: 802.11n NIC
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.889457] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.889474] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 000B81A264C8
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.981586] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  340.981613] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  341.034610] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  341.064199] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  341.093994] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Sep  5 16:47:56 pi-3-test systemd-udevd[433]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Sep  5 16:47:57 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
```

There is no further message until the device is unplugged.

If you then plug in a working WiFi adapter, say MT7601, `dhcpcd` notices the new wlan0 interface, waits for a carrier, logs `wlan0: carrier acquired` and starts a new instance of `wpa_supplicant`:

```
Sep  5 16:50:54 pi-3-test kernel: [  519.698607] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Sep  5 16:50:54 pi-3-test kernel: [  519.839852] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601, bcdDevice= 0.00
Sep  5 16:50:54 pi-3-test kernel: [  519.839879] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep  5 16:50:54 pi-3-test kernel: [  519.839897] usb 1-1.2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
Sep  5 16:50:54 pi-3-test kernel: [  519.839914] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
Sep  5 16:50:54 pi-3-test kernel: [  519.839932] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1.0
Sep  5 16:50:55 pi-3-test mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Sep  5 16:50:55 pi-3-test mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Sep  5 16:50:55 pi-3-test kernel: [  520.188591] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Sep  5 16:50:55 pi-3-test kernel: [  520.321273] mt7601u 1-1.2:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
Sep  5 16:50:55 pi-3-test kernel: [  520.328011] mt7601u 1-1.2:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
Sep  5 16:50:55 pi-3-test kernel: [  520.791567] mt7601u 1-1.2:1.0: EEPROM ver:0d fae:00
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  521.029278] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test kernel: [  521.042449] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test systemd-udevd[471]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd-run-hooks[491]: wlan0: starting wpa_supplicant
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: DUID 00:01:00:01:26:d1:11:c3:b8:27:eb:80:3f:4b
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: wlan0: IAID 76:b0:23:61
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test dhcpcd[357]: wlan0: adding address fe80::f412:3b9a:bf52:71ac
Sep  5 16:50:56 pi-3-test avahi-daemon[299]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::f412:3b9a:bf52:71ac.
```

etc etc. The new instance of `wpa_supplicant` looks like this:

```
root       494  0.0  0.2  10996  2436 ?        Ss   12:59   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

You can tell `dhcpcd` to not wait for carrier by adding the `-K` flag, and then reloading systemd, but this did not work for me to make the RTL8188 device hotpluggable:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d/wait.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

The RTL8188 device can be brought up manually by running the appropriate wpa_supplicant command: `wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext` but I think the better solution is to throw the RTL8188 back into the parts drawer and use something which works out of the box, such as the MT7601. Or buy a Raspberry Pi 3 or later, which has working inbuilt WiFi.